# how to resume ddrescue process?

Tags: hard-drive, ddrescue

I have to recover my 1TB USB HD. I'm using `ddrescue` to accomplish this.  Is there a way that I can resume `ddrescue` once I start it?

I'm using the command:

```
ddrescue /dev/sdd1 ./bye1t.dd_rescue.image
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*ddrescue* can be resumed, but it requires a log file to be able to do so. The log file will record the progress that ddrescue has made so far, and restarting ddrescue will read the log file and start where it left off.

The log file would be the third parameter:

```
ddrescue /dev/sdd1 ./bye1t.dd_rescue.image ~/sdd1.log
```

If you have already started a ddrescue run without a log file and cancel it, the next time ddrescue runs, it will start at the beginning since it has no record of what has already been recovered.

*Note*: [ddrescue](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue) and [dd_rescue](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Dd_rescue) are different programs.

Comment: So if I started initially with a log file and will run the same command again, it will automatically resume from last log position? _**/edit:** it does start from the last position._

Comment: How about changing config, is it possible to change config and for example reduce number of retries and speed up process?

Answer (score 10):

Even if you forgot to specify a logfile, there may be hope:

[Generate-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Generate-mode)

So you didn't read the tutorial and started ddrescue without a logfile. Now, two days later, your computer crashed and you can't know how much data ddrescue managed to save. And even worse, you can't resume the rescue; you have to restart it from the very beginning.

Or maybe you started copying a drive with `dd conv=noerror,sync` and are now in the same situation described above. In this case, note that you can't use a copy made by dd unless it was invoked with the `sync` conversion argument.

Don't despair (yet). Ddrescue can in some cases generate an approximate logfile, from the input file and the (partial) copy, that is almost as good as an exact logfile. It makes this by simply assuming that sectors containng all zeros were not rescued.

However, if the destination of the copy was a drive or a partition, (or an existing regular file and truncation was not requested), most probably you will need to restart ddrescue from the very beginning. (This time with a logfile, of course). The reason is that old data may be present in the drive that have not been overwritten yet, and may be thus non-tried but non-zero.

For example, if you first tried one of these commands:

```
ddrescue infile outfile
```

or

```
dd if=infile of=outfile conv=noerror,sync
```

you can generate an approximate logfile with this command:

```
ddrescue --generate-mode infile outfile logfile
```

Comment: Is infile the disk being rescued, and outfile the rescue data?

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you should always specify a logfile as the third parameter, which will allow resuming. Since you didn't do that, that's not going to help you here. If you know approximately what point the process got to, you can use the `--input-position` and `--output-position` parameters to start from that point (make sure to set both those parameters to the same value, otherwise the output will be corrupted).

Comment: According to https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html, `--output-position` defaults to the `--input-position=...` value.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not specify a log file as third parameter, resuming cannot be done automatically . You could create a logfile by hand if you know the already rescued sectors, the syntax is easy. Just start another dummy rescue to another file while specifying a log and let it read different areas. Then edit the log to represent the already rescued areas in your first file. Now re-run your previous command but give the name of the log file as the third parameter. ddrescue will then resume on the first untried sector.

Answer (score 2):

Per https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_cloning it seems
that with the `conv=noerror,sync` switch, `dd`does in fact add zeroes **at the end** of a block, not exactly where the read errors occurred. This is contrary to information in Miles Wolbe's answer from 2013-08-29.

For instance, if a correct sequence is `198123283` and there's a read error in the middle it will write `198283000`, not `198000283`.

So in case there were actually read errors the proposed method won't be accurate- there will be areas which would have been readable which will end up filled with zeroes, yet will be considered "rescued".

By the way, it's a good practice to begin such a recovery attempt by filling the destination drive with zeroes (or at least the free space, which can be done with WinHex for example).

Comment: Hi GabrielB, welcome to Super User. I have edited your answer, but I'm not sure that it is enough to stand alone- perhaps you could further edit it to include a small section that addresses the original question too?

Comment: If I remember correctly I wanted to comment Miles Wolbe's answer but couldn't as a new member, so I had to post a new answer. If it's possible, feel free to move the above post where it should appear and delete this one.